# how to do overlay scroll in css

Tags: html, css

I have two divs in html outer and  inner , so i want that outer div having a scrollbar overlay , i have my html like below:

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">

   </div> 
</div>
```

i have tried this in css

```
.outer{
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     width: 300px;
     height: 95vh;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow-y: hidden;
}
.outer:hover{
   overflow-y: auto;  
}

.inner{
   width 100%;
   height 100%;
   position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It seems like your screenshot is from a mac, and your second screenshot is not a mac.  Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I just copy your code and I have the scroll-bar in my `div`.
I add CSS to custom scroll-bar.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/stefalber/e4Lad6yv/1/) my JSfiddle.